# Join string to the left side of output

Tags: sed, concatenation

How can I join a string from the left side to the output?

For example: we want to join parameter="file/"

remark: file=/dir1/dir2/ (file has a value)

```
    echo  aaa bbb |  awk '{print $2}' | sed ....
```

Will print

```
    /dir1/dir2/bbb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is good, this should be enough.

```
sed "s|\(.*\)|$VARIABLE\1|"
```

Comment: echo  aaa bbb |  awk '{print $2}' | sed "s/\(.*\)/$file\/\1/" not work -(

Comment: file is parameter for example file=/etc/sysconfig

Answer (score 0):

```
echo aaa bbb | awk '{print "file/"$2}'
```

Comment: I have case that file is parameter with value
how to change your syntax in order to enable file=/etc/sysconfig

Comment: `echo aaa bbb | awk '{print "'$your_var'"$2}'`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
echo aaa bbb | awk '{ print "file/" $2 }'
```

Comment: but if file=/etc/sysconfig what then?

Comment: lidia, you are correct, you changed the question after I replied and my solution no longer applies.